# How does validation work in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To set validation inside a Model in Rails, I should write something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

I can't figure out how this works. It seems like it is calling a method named `validates` and is passing parameters, but this can't be because, I believe I cannot call a method directly in a class body.

So what is actually happening in here?

### update

From the answers it seems like this is calling a method from the inhereted `Base` class but then why does this not work?:

```
class Parent
  def foo
    puts "called foo"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
 foo
 foo
end
```

Comment: def self.foo will work for you

Comment: you might to change the title's question as it doesn't reflect what you really wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "but this can't be because (I believe) you cannot call a method directly in a class body."

But that's not true --- code is being executed as the class is loaded

Consider this:

```
class Hi
  puts "yo"
end
```

You'll get:

```
yo
 => nil
```

the puts is executed when it's loaded. So you can use this to create other methods or do whatever you need.

Comment: change it to `def self.foo` and you're golden

Comment: Reason: you defined `foo` as an instance method and need it to be a class method to be in scope of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think you cannot call a method on the class body?  These are class methods, and that is how they are called - see for example the bit on validations [here](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) and the definition of validates in the class method of the api [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

You can see it working here:

```
 class Foo
   def self.bar
     p 'hello'
   end
end

Foo.bar #=> hello

class Thing < Foo
  bar
end
 #=> hello
```

Comment: Well I wrote a sample class in ruby that tried to call one of its own methods in the class body and it told me "`undefined local variable or method 'bar' for class Foo:Class`"

Comment: Depends on what kind of method it is. If it's a class method defined as `def self.foo` then do `Class.foo` and you're fine. If it's an instance method defined as `def bar` then you need an instance of `Class` first, like so: `Class.new.bar`. Then it will work just fine.